# How to remove duplicates of ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> and sort array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Lets say I have an array of an array of strings:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayOfArray= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Maybe it could look something like this(eg.):
arrayOfArray = [[A,1,B,2],[C,1,D,2],[C,1,D,2],[A,1,B,2]]

In the end I want this(duplicates was removed):
arrayOfArrayNoDuplicates = [[C,1,D,2],[A,1,B,2]]

Then as a final step I want this array of array to be sorted on the first item in the array.
Looks like this array of array maybe was sorted on the A or the B.
arrayOfArraySorted = [[A,1,B,2],[C,1,D,2]]

Is this possible without also sorting the inner array? I want to keep the order within the array "A,1,B,2".

I hope you understand want I want to do:)

/M

Comment: Instead of list you should use set.It does not allow duplicates and particulary use LinkedHashSet.It maintains insertion order

Comment: But is this really working for Array of array?

Comment: Yes it might work..i have not tried it before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

It functions like an array, it dedupes

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a `HashSet` or similar to remove duplicates from your collection of data (sets can only contain unique elements). I'm unsure how effective this will be against `ArrayList`'s of varying contents though, so you might be best off extending `ArrayList<String>` and implementing your own `bool equals(Object a)` method (for your inner arrays).

To then sort your collection you should using [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), you can then pass this a custom `Comparator` to sort them by whichever order you please. (A comparator lets you provide a method that takes 2 objects and rates their order.) Or if you've extended `ArrayList<String>` simply add the `compare` method to your class and add `implements Comparator`.

An example Comparator would be;

```
import java.util.*;
class ALComparator implements Comparator<ArrayList<String>>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<String> b)
    {
        if(a.size()==b.size())
            return 1;
        if(a.size()==0)
            return -1;
        if(b.size()==0)
            return 1;
        return a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Set with a Comparator fot that.

```
Set<List<String>> list = new TreeSet<ArrayList<String>>(
             new Comparator<List<String>>() {
               public int compare(List<String> left, List<String> right) {
                  //check here if equal, before or after...    

               }
             }
         );
```